# For which $k$ do we get $f_k(t)=1$ ?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

We have the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$, the element $a=x^2+3$ of $R$ and the ideal $I=(a)$ of $R$.

If $f_k(x)=12x^2+k$, ($k\in \mathbb{Z}$), $R_1=R/I$ and the element $t$ of $R_1$ is the equivalence class of $x$, then $f_k(t)=1$ in $R_1$ for which $k$ ?

$$$$

We have that $t\equiv x \pmod 5$.

We also have that $f_k(t)=1\Rightarrow 12t^2+k=1 \Rightarrow 12t^2+k-1=0$.

So, we have to check for which $k$ the remainder of the division of $12x^2+k-1$ and $x^2+3$ is equal to $0$, or not?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach. Note that $12x^2+1\equiv 2x^2+6=2(x^2+3)\mod 5$ , so you get $k=2$

Comment: I see!! Thank you!! @Peter